# Try to get the value of a td when I press a button

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, rows

I create a table into a php file with 2 rows and a button on each last `<td>`:

```
<table id="filterTableMsg" border="1" class="TF">
<tbody><tr><th>Message Title</th><th>Message</th><th>Schedule Date</th><th>share</th>   </tr>

<tr class="row_hover">
<td>hello</td>
<td>hello message</td>
<td>2014-04-09 00:11:51</td>
<td><button id="FBshare">share it!</button></td>
</tr>

<tr class="row_hover">
<td>hello again</td>
<td>hello new message</td>
<td>2014-04-08 10:15:21</td>
<td><button id="FBshare">share it!</button></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

When I press a button (`id="FBshare"`) I need to get the row index and then get the value of cell[0], cell[1] and cell[2], with jQuery.

I try to solve this with this code but it returns 'undefined' :

```
$(function() {      
 /*when i click on the FBshare button*/
  $(document).on('click', '#FBshare', function(e){  
         e.preventDefault();
         var mytable = $('#filterTableMsg tr:eq(1) td');//for example to get the 2nd row
            alert(mytable.eq(2).html());//here i try to get the html of the 2nd cell but i get 'undifined
     });
```

I can get the index of the row of the button by writing this:

```
alert($(this).closest('tr').index()); // but I can't make them work all together.
```

Has anyone faced the same or similar problem?

Please give a hand

Comment: One issue I see is that you have multiple elements with the same Id (FBshare).  Id's need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<table id="filterTableMsg" border="1" class="TF">
    <tbody><tr><th>Message Title</th><th>Message</th><th>Schedule Date</th><th>share</th>   </tr>

    <tr id="row_1" class="row_hover">
        <td>hello</td>
        <td>hello message</td>
        <td>2014-04-09 00:11:51</td>
        <td>
            <button data-row="row_1" class="FBshare">share it!</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="row_2" class="row_hover">
        <td>hello again</td>
        <td>hello new message</td>
        <td>2014-04-08 10:15:21</td>
        <td>
            <button data-row="row_2" class="FBshare">share it!</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the HTML, I changed the FBshare to a class (since you can't duplicate IDs in a valid DOM) and added a data-row attribute. This is also added as the ID of the TR element, and should be very easy to generate with PHP.

```
$('.FBshare').click( function(){
    var rowID = $(this).attr('data-row');
    $('#' + rowID + 'td:not(:last-child)').each( function(){
        alert( $(this).text() );
    } );
} );
```

Then the click event, which is bound to the new class grabs the value of the data-row attribute, creates a new selector to select the TDs within them except for the last child, loops through each TD and alerts the `.text()` value.

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/L8XaL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Base on Sridhar R provided code i make another quick example code  to make it clear to see:

```
<table id="filterTableMsg" border="1" class="TF">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Message Title</th>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Schedule Date</th>
            <th>share</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row_hover">
            <td>hello</td>
            <td>hello message</td>
            <td>2014-04-09 00:11:51</td>
            <td>
                <button class="FBshare">share it!</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row_hover">
            <td>hello again</td>
            <td>hello new message</td>
            <td>2014-04-08 10:15:21</td>
            <td>
                <button class="FBshare">share it!</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="output">
</div>
```

**Note the changed of class instead of id!**

```
$(function () {
    /*when i click on the FBshare button*/
    $(document).on('click', '.FBshare', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
        var idex1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();
        var idex2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
        var idex3 = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();

        $('.output').html('<p><b>index:</b>' + idex + ' ' + idex1 + ' ' + idex2 + ' ' + idex3 + '</p>');
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2czg5/6/

Comment: thank you very much , for your help, all solutions work perfect and exactly as i need.